# Subtract a single vector element from List of vectors

Tags: r, list, function, lapply

I have a list `r` containing n vectors of different length.
And a separate vector `a` also of length n

```
x <- 1:100
r <- slider(x,.size=5)

a <- 1:length(r)
```

From every element in each vector of the list `r` I want to subtract an element of `a`.
So the first element of `a` shall be subtracted from every element of the first vector of `r`.

Something like this, but on a larger scale and keeping the vectors in the list `r`

```
r[1]-a[1]
r[2]-a[2]
r[3]-a[3]
```

This gives me `Error in r[1] - n[1] : non-numeric argument to binary operator`

Disclaimer: The vectors of `r` in the example do NOT have different lengths. I do not know how to do this when generating the example.

Comment: Which library is `slider` function from ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Map` :

```
Map(`-`, r, a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Same result from @RonakShah can be obtained with:

```
mapply(`-`,r,a)
```

Output:

```
[[1]]
[1] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

[[2]]
[1] -1  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7

[[3]]
 [1] -2 -1  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
```

Comment: Exact same as Ronaks.  `Map` is simply `mapply(..., simplify = FALSE)`

Comment: @Sotos Althought they appear as different functions!

Answer (score 0):

We could use a `for` loop

```
out <- vector('list', length(r))
for(i in seq_along(r)) {
       out[[i]] <- r[[i]] - a[i]
}
```